# Where do the arguments in functions passed to higher-order functions come from?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I'm working through Eloquent Javascript and I'm having trouble understanding something. Perhaps I've missed something along the way. This is the solution given for chapter 5 (higher-order functions), exercise 1, which takes the elements in the different arrays and puts them all in a single array:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
console.log(arrays.reduce(function(flat, current) {
  return flat.concat(current);
}, []));
```

My problem is: I have absolutely no clue why the arguments "flat" and "current" work in this situation. The entire chapter reads through assuming the reader understands what's going on here but I have absolutely no idea why this works. It doesn't appear that "flat" and "current" are defined anywhere. Another short example is this one where the author explains how the reduce method works (problem area in bold):

```
function reduce(array, combine, start) {
  var current = start;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    current = combine(current, array[i]);
  return current;
}

**console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}, 0));**
```

Where in the world did "a" and "b" come from and why does this piece of code work? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You're defining a function that's called by `reduce`. `reduce` supplies the `a` and `b` arguments to your function. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: Thank you very much, everyone. Every answer was informative and I'd upvote them all if I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flat` and `current` don't need to be declared anywhere, they are *parameters* to the anonymous function that is passed to `Array.reduce`.

One way to illustrate this is to modify your second example to use `Array.reduce` directly using an anonymous function with parameters `a` and `b`.  Look at this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(a, b) {
    console.log("a: " + a + " b: " + b);
    return a + b;
});
```

The console will now show:

```
a: 1 b: 2
a: 3 b: 3
a: 6 b: 4
10
```

What's happening is that the anonymous `function(a, b) {...}` is called with `(1, 2)`, which returns `3`, which is passed in again `(3, 3)` which returns `6`, which is passed in as the first argument `(6, 4)`, which returns the final answer `10`.

Another illustration is to use *a second argument* to `Array.reduce`, say `10`, to see what's going on. That `10` is used as the `initialValue`.  So:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(a, b) {
    console.log("a: " + a + " b: " + b);
    return a + b;
}, 10);
```

The trace is:

```
a: 10 b: 1
11 b: 2
13 b: 3
16 b: 4
20
```

You can work out how that happened.

Comment: If only the author would've explained it like this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `reduce` can be a little confusing in the beginning. It is a native function that takes two parameters. One is a callback function and the other one is any value.

The idea is that in the callback function you can use the values of the array one at a time to process a result. To do that it iterates over the array values and passes them to the callback function you defined one at a time and for every loop it takes the value of the last loop and passes it as well.

Let's say you want to sum all numbers in an array:

```
//your array
var numbers = [4,7,3];

//your initial value
var initialValue = 0;

//your function
function sum(iteratingValue, arrayValue) {
    return iteratingValue + arrayValue;
}

var result = numbers.reduce(sum, initialValue);
```

Now, you can name your callback function parameters whatever you like, `a` and `b`, `start` and `finish`, `fish` and `duck`. It won't matter, `reduce` will pass the values in the same order.

Here is the definition by MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

> reduce executes the callback function once for each element present in the array, excluding holes in the array, receiving four arguments: the initial value (or value from the previous callback call), the value of the current element, the current index, and the array over which iteration is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

First, let us touch the core of the question. Let's suppose you have a `function`, like this:

```
function func1(myfunc, arr) {
    //Do something, which will result in having variables called param1 and param2
    myfunc(param1, param2);
}
```

Let's see what happens. `func1` takes `myfunc` and `arr` as parameters. `myfunc` will be passed when `func1` is called. `arr` is an array.

Now, let's suppose you call it this way:

```
func1(function(a, b) {
    //do something with a and b
}, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

You are calling `func1`, by passing a `function` and an array. The array is obvious, so let's see the `function`. The `function` expects two parameters and will do something with them. You do not have to define `a` or `b` when you call `func1`, since it is `func1`'s internal job to create and initialize them. So, `func1` will do its internal things and call your function passed as a parameter. Now, let's see your example:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
console.log(arrays.reduce(function(flat, current) {
  return flat.concat(current);
}, []));
```

Here, you call `arrays.reduce` (which is very similar to `func1` in the general description). You pass a `function` and an array. Again, the array is obvious, but the question is, how `flat` and `current` are defined. The answer is that it is `arrays.reduce`'s internal job to create and initialize them. As about the `reduce` prototype function, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).